# Python: Efficient script to get some value from XML doc or not?

Tags: python, xml, libxml2

I have the following XML document

```
<data>
    <point address="com.example.www" time="Jul 30, 2013 10:02:56 PM" protocol="http" type="2" body="404 Not Found" name="Example Site" />
    <point address="com.example.test" time="Jul 29, 2013 07:45:03 AM" protocol="https" type="2" body="This is a test" name="Test.example" />
    .......
</data>
```

I used the following Python code:

```
import libxml2

def ReadValue(pn, dt):
    return [attr.content for attr in input_file.xpathEval("/data/point[@protocol='%s']/@%s" % (pn, dt))]

protocol = ["http", "https"]
data_type = ["body", "type", "time", "name"]

for i in protocol:
    for j in data_type:
        print ReadValue(i, j)

exit()
```

I suspect that `ReadValue` is the bottleneck when I parse over 200k tags. It ran so slow that even I can't Ctrl-C the script while it is running. Is there any better implementation than using mentioned code above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be however there is another inefficiency.

You are looping for each protocol and each data_type and then running an xpath for each combination which requires a costly call for each one and I suspect a costly search as I don't thing there is an index.

You would be better off doing one pass over the XML and reading the protocol and data_type as you read each element and collect the data that way